# Chart.min.js - sometimes the chart is displayed and sometimes not

Tags: chart.js

hello I have the following problem I use the plugin Chart.js to display statistics now I have the following problem sometimes the chart is displayed and sometimes not see screenshot
I have asked in a Discord Chat but that did not help, i hope i can get help here

Chart.js Version:2.1.4

The Code:

```js
function LoadProviderChart() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var providercount = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('providercount_' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[4]));
    console.log(providercount);
    providercount = Object.keys(providercount).map(function (key) {
        return [key, providercount[key]];
    })

    providercount.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b[1].count - a[1].count;
    })
    var cutProviderCount = providercount.slice(0, 6);
    if(window.ProviderChart != null) {
            window.ProviderChart.destroy();
            console.log("ProviderChart destroyed");
    }
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Rubik';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#fff';
    var ctxB = document.getElementById("barChart").getContext('2d');
    var config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: { 
            labels: cutProviderCount.map(function(x) { return x[0] }),
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Games of Providers',
                data: cutProviderCount.map(function(x) { return x[1].count }),
                backgroundColor: "" + getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--highlight_color').toString().replace(' ', '') + "",
            }],
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                gridLines:{
                  display: false,
                },
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true
                }
              }],
              xAxes: [{
                gridLines:{
                display:false,
            },
            }]
            }
          }
    }
    window.ProviderChart = new Chart(ctxB, config);
    });
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might want to start and try to use a more up to date version of chart.js, the version you are using is 6 years old. You can safely update to 2.9.4 without any breaking changes or 3.8.2 but than you need to adjust your code.

Comment: @LeeLenalee thanks that was the problem